# Javascript function stops immediately

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I have a function which enables the button 2(id keuze1) and button 3 ( id keuze 3) If i press button 1 (id = naam).

```js
function init() {
  let startKnop = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", startClicked, false);
}

function startClicked(event) {
  let knop2 = document.getElementById("keuze1");
  knop2.removeAttribute("disabled");
  let knop3 = document.getElementById("keuze2");
  knop3.removeAttribute("disabled");
  toonVraag();
}

function toonVraag(event) {
  let i = vraagTeller.value;
  let vraag = document.getElementById('vraag');
  vraag.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<label for="naam">Code: </label><input type="text" id="naam" />
</div>
<button disabled>Start</button>
<div>
  <p id="vraag">Een vraag</p>
  <button id="keuze1" disabled>Keuze1</button>
  <button id="keuze2" disabled>Keuze2</button>
</div>
```

So it successfully runs the function `startClicked()`, but stops immediately.
If I add the code `event.preventDefault()` it doesn't go through to changing the text from my element(id = vraag).

Comment: What is `vraagTeller`?

Comment: I suggest you to check the browsers developer console for errors.

Comment: I'm so sorry i forgot to delete that. It doesn't really add any value to the function.  I deleted it and still got the same problem.

Comment: Works just fine ... exemplified in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/j4mnc2L8/)

Comment: It tells me that 'vraag' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work just fine, as exemplified in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/j4mnc2L8/)

I did some clean-up though:

- Removed the `disabled` attribute from the first button
- Removed the `</div>` from the 2nd line
- Added call to the `init()` function

As such:

```js
function init() {

    let startKnop = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", startClicked, false);

}

init();

function startClicked(event) {
    let knop2 = document.getElementById("keuze1");
    knop2.removeAttribute("disabled");

    let knop3 = document.getElementById("keuze2");
    knop3.removeAttribute("disabled");

    toonVraag();
}

function toonVraag(event) {

    let vraag = document.getElementById('vraag');
    vraag.innerHTML = "Hello World";

}
```

```html
<label for="naam">Code: </label><input type="text" id="naam" />
<button>Start</button>
<div>
    <p id="vraag">Een vraag</p>
    <button id="keuze1" disabled>Keuze1</button>
    <button id="keuze2" disabled>Keuze2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Protzoid First of all thank for your answer. But I Still can't get it to work. If have finals tomorrow of Js and I really need to figure this out. 
Here is all my code https://jsfiddle.net/wotsepotse/g1Ljjgc7/1/. You have to  place 1KK1K as code then hit tab  and you will see what i mean. Really Thanks in advance for looking at this.